# Galois theory Primitive roots

Tags: galois-theory

I am a bit unsure as to how to find sub fields of field extensions of the rationals containing primitive roots. A specific question which I am stuck on is find all subfields $K$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{16})$, $\zeta_{16}$ a root of unity of order sixteen, such that $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=2$.

I have attempted a similar question: find all subfields $K$ of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{133})$ such that $[K:\Bbb{Q}]=3$. I was able to get a bit further with the Question by splitting up the galois group $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{133})/\Bbb{Q})$ into $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{7})/\Bbb{Q})\times Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_{19})/\Bbb{Q})$ and looking for subgroups of order 36 (=108/3) which I would then use to find the fields but I was wondering whether there was a more sensible way to do this? Possibly a way that would work also for the first question where you can't split into coprime factors?

Thanks for your help,
Harriet

Comment: I took the liberty of TeXifying your post. Makes it more readable, doesn't it? Click the `edit`-button below your post to see the changes. Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/11619) for more about LaTeX/MathJax. Trust me, it really pays to study TeX a bit. You will most likely be using it when writing your diploma thesis or whatnot.

Comment: To get started with the actual question you should first write down a description of the Galois group. Undoubtedly it has been explained to you in the course material that $Gal(\Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)/\Bbb{Q})$ is naturally isomorphic to $\Bbb{Z}_n^*$. When $n=16$, this group has order $8$, so finding all the subgroups of index two should not be too difficult. Then you need to identify the fixed fields of those subgroups, and you are done.

Comment: And I think that when you find them, you’ll be thoroughly disappointed. I was, anyway.